# Removing Items from Reading List

Tags: safari, reading-list

How do I remove items (individual or all) from Reading List on my iMac (OS X 10.6.8)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running OS 10.9.x right now, but I don't think it should be too different. When you open the reading list by clicking the little glasses (I think that's what it was- it may be under the same book icon as bookmarks), mouseover the item you want to delete, and you should see a tiny x in a circle appear in the top left of that item. Click to delete it.

Comment: Thanks AgentRF. That used to work but no more. My reading list has gotten huge & I’d finally decided to clear all the items, but that too won’t respond.

Comment: So your question was more along the lines of mass-deletion, not one-by-one?

Answer (score 0):

sidebar for reading list, has a tiny x to remove that one item
control-click it to get an option for delete all
found on https://discussions.apple.com/message/24035730#24035730

Answer (score 0):

Hold "control" down as you click on reading list item. In the menu that appears choose "delete". You can delete more than one item using "shift" or "command" keys.

Answer (score 0):

hold control key, click on item, select remove.
that works now after update